# ASPNET Session databases disappeared after reboot

Tags: sql, sql-server

Had a bit of panic recently when our database server automatically rebooted after installing a critical update (Windows Server 2012 R2). We sorted the cause of restart, but the problem is that after the server restarted our ASP.NET SQL Sessions database didn't have any tables in it and the web application crashed completely. There was no hard reset, but in a way it was a forced reset caused by the OS which damaged our data. Question is why did database get corrupted and how to avoid it? Thanks for any advice

Comment: ASP.NET session objects are stored in tempdb by default, which is recreated empty each time SQL Server is restarted.  Make sure the ASPState_Startup exists in the master database that runs on startup to recreate the objects.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202032/adding-tempdb-items-on-startup-in-sql-server.  You could also create a permanent aspstate database to avoid the issue.

Comment: Hi Dan, we recreated the ASP.NET sessions with aspnet_regiis tool when we had the problem. Now I definitely have ASPState_Startup stored procedure in master database and it is registered to startup automatically. I checked it with this SQL statement: 
SELECT [name]
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'P'
  AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'ExecIsStartUp') = 1;
There is also a CreateTemTables procedure in the ASPState database, so everything should work. However, I'm giving 99% that we had same setup before and it failed for some reason, but now we lost (?) an opportunity to check whether it was the case